# Specifying Optimization Policy while using TensorRT Inference Server

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

I have managed to successfully serve a Tensorflow Object Detection API model using TensorRT Inference Server and the config file (`config.pbtxt`) is as follows:

```
name: "first_model"
platform: "tensorflow_savedmodel"
max_batch_size: 1
input [
  {
    name: "inputs"
    data_type: TYPE_UINT8
    dims: [ -1, -1, 3 ]
  }
]
output [
  {
    name: "detection_boxes"
    data_type: TYPE_FP32
    dims: [ 100, 4 ]
  },
  {
    name: "detection_scores"
    data_type: TYPE_FP32
    dims: [ 100 ]
  },
  {
    name: "detection_classes"
    data_type: TYPE_FP32
    dims: [ 100 ]
  }
]
```

I was going through the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-inference-server-guide/docs/model_configuration.html) and it turns out there is a way to specify [optimization settings](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-inference-server-guide/docs/model_configuration.html#optimization-policy) for the model in the `config.pbtxt` as well. However the documentation fails to mention how can one specify these optimization settings. I tried adding the below lines to the config file

```
optimization_policy [
  {
    level:1
  }
]
```

and tried serving the model but instead got an error: `Can't parse /models/first_model/config.pbtxt as text proto`. However if I remove the lines relating to the `optimization_policy` I do not face any issues while serving.

How can I specify the optimization policy/setting in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Answering it myself. Got the answer by raising an issue on the office Github repo.

You will need to format your `config.pbtxt` using protobuf text format following the schema [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorrt-inference-server/blob/master/src/core/model_config.proto#L358):

I believe what you want is:

```
optimization {  graph { level: 1 } }
```